# algolia instantsearch only show result that matches particular query (react)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, algolia, instantsearch, react-instantsearch

I'm using react instant search to show list of users in select options. I managed to show all the users in select option but **I want to only show users with admin role** (role === 'admin').

Ofcourse I can do this in client side by filtering the hits on role but is there
any way to achieve this with react instant search?

This is how I showed all user.

AlgoliaProvider.js

```js
import React from "react";
import algoliasearch from "algoliasearch/lite";
import { InstantSearch } from "react-instantsearch-dom";

const searchClient = algoliasearch(
  process.env.REACT_APP_ALGOLIA_APP_ID,
  process.env.REACT_APP_ALGOLIA_SEARCH_KEY
);

const AlgoliaProvider = ({ indexName, children, ...rest }) => {
  return (
    <InstantSearch indexName={indexName} searchClient={searchClient} {...rest}>
      {children}
    </InstantSearch>
  );
};

export default AlgoliaProvider;
```

AutoCompleteSelect.js

```js
import React from 'react';
import {  Select } from 'antd';
import { connectAutoComplete } from 'react-instantsearch-dom';

const { Option } = Select;

const AutoCompleteSelect = ({
  hits,
  refine,
  ...rest
}) => {
  const handleSuggestion = value => {
    refine(value);
  };

    return (
      <Select showSearch onSearch={handleSuggestion} {...rest}>
        {hits.map(user => (
          <Option
            key={user.uid}
            value={user.uid}
          >
            <span>{user.name}</span>
          </Option>
        ))}
      </Select>
    );
 
};

export default connectAutoComplete(AutoCompleteSelect);
```

App.js

```js
 <AlgoliaProvider indexName="User">             
   <AutoCompleteSelect placeholder="user search" />
 </AlgoliaProvider>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the faceting feature to achieve this.
Read more about it here: https://www.algolia.com/doc/guides/managing-results/refine-results/faceting/

I have configured one such facet via the UI (algolia frontend) and then I use it like this in instantSearch:

```
<InstantSearch searchClient={.... >

<Configure
   hitsPerPage={<Number>}
   filters={`role:${user.role}`} />
...
...
</InstantSearch>
```

See the filters part in the code, 'role' needs to be added as a facet in the configuration (via ui or code).

Answer (score 1):

using `Searchstate`

```
<InstantSearch
    ....
    searchState={{
        role: 'admin',
    }}
}}
```

More on: https://www.algolia.com/doc/api-reference/widgets/ui-state/react/

Comment: This does seems to be what i need but I get an error after adding this. Uncaught Error: You can't switch <InstantSearch> from being uncontrolled to controlled
    at InstantSearch.componentDidUpdate.

Comment: https://github.com/algolia/react-instantsearch/issues/1113

Comment: thanks. I managed to fix that error. But the role: 'admin' part doesnt seem to work. I also tried using filters: 'role:admin' but still the same. searchState={{
        query: 'some query',
    }} works but this is not what I need. Can you tell me where you got the   searchState={{
        role: 'admin',
    }} part?

Comment: https://www.algolia.com/doc/api-reference/widgets/instantsearch/react/#widget-param-searchstate